# Can't add event handlers to content created using .getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Question edited for clarity**

I make an AJAX call, using the `$.getJSON()` method, and add some elements to the page in the callback function:

```
$.getJSON("pathToFile/file.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.lst, function(i, item) { /* Add HTML elements to the page.. */ });
});
```

It all displays correctly, but the event handlers I've added for the elements don't work:

```
$(".newElement").on("click", "input", function() {
    alert("Something happened..");
});
```

Nothing happens when i click on the input elements. What am I missing?

**Explanation**

As @jbabey kindly pointed out, [the documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) states that you have to bind the event handler to an existing element. The code doesn't work because the elements don't exist when the event handler is applied.

Comment: Where did you add the `.on()` code? It must come after the elements are added.

Comment: This code can definitely be improved. Passing a callback to `.html()` without having it return the new content does not make sense. I suggest you work more with DOM elements than with HTML strings. This will make things clearer.

Comment: Does that multi-line string setup work in all the newer browsers? I guess it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any errors anywhere, or just nothing happens? Are you able to see any useful information in the traffic (fiddler, firebug, etc)?

I would first suggest changing your usage of $.getJSON to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so that you can add an error handler, then we can investigate the actual problem.

A good article on the different ways to use jQuery to make ajax calls can be found here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: That's interesting and useful information, but he said the content is correctly shown.

Comment: The content shows correctly without any errors. Thanks for the info jbabey :).

Comment: if the content is correct (sorry i missed that part) then i would check that your html is well formatted. constructing HTML via string concatenation can cause some unexpected behavior. check out a simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/HQpj6/

Comment: Hi jbabey, thx for your answer. I've edited the post above explaining that .live() works and .on() doesn't. I still don't really understand why, but I guess I can live with .live().

Comment: from jquery's on() documention: "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()." - if the ajax call has not finished when you are calling .on(), then the div with class chaAdv would not yet exist. If this is the case, live would work and on would fail.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the info you provided. If you find any problem with the solution please let me know. Thanks for your answers :).